# gcloud miss k8s master after the end of the trial

Tags: gcloud

The master disappeared after the end of the trial period.
Worker nodes and disk remain.
Can I get the master back somehow?
Already tied up and paid for in gcloud.

At the moment, he proposes to make only a new cluster.

Workers are in the Compute Engine

Answer (score 1):

Citing the documentation:

> #### End of the Free Trial
>
> The Free Trial ends when you use all of your credit, or after 90 days, whichever happens first. At that time, the following conditions apply:
>
> - To continue using Google Cloud, you must [upgrade to a paid Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade).
> - All resources you created during the trial are stopped.
> - **Any data you stored in Compute Engine is lost.**
> - Your Cloud Billing account enters a 30-day grace period, during which you can recover resources and data you stored in any Google Cloud services during the trial period.
> - You might receive a message stating that your Cloud Billing account has been canceled, which only indicates that your account has been suspended to prevent charges.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Free: Docs: GCP Free tier: End](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end)*

According to the official documentation, specifically on the part of:

> - **Any data you stored in Compute Engine is lost.**

I suggest you to create a new `GKE` cluster.

`GKE` nodes are [Compute Engine VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#nodes) that `GKE` creates on your behalf when you create a cluster.

As for the control plane (master):

> The *control plane* runs the control plane processes, including the Kubernetes API server, scheduler, and core resource controllers. The lifecycle of the control plane is managed by GKE when you create or delete a cluster. This includes upgrades to the Kubernetes version running on the control plane, which GKE performs automatically, or manually at your request if you prefer to upgrade earlier than the automatic schedule.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Cluster architecture: Control plane](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#control_plane)*

---

If it came to the situation that you would like to inspect the disks for any data still stored on them, you could try to mount them to the other `VM` by editing the `VM` configuration (`Additional disks`):

[image: Additional disks]

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Free](https://cloud.google.com/free)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kuberentes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Cluster architecture](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture)*

---

Alternatively, you can reach Google Cloud Support:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Support Hub](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)*

Comment: @Red Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?